# How do I create a horizontal text slider in JQuery and/or CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a text slider to slide between 4 different sentences. I can't get it to work, and as a matter of fact, I can't get the code to function at all. I need to start fresh, but I have no idea how to create one that will switch between sentences.

Any help on creating one with CSS3 or jQuery, as I don't really have a preference, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post the relevant code so we can potentially see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setup for containers (using span's in this example):

```
<div id="parent_container">
    <span>Sentence once</span>
    <span>Sentence two</span>
    <span>Sentence three</span>
    <span>Sentence four</span>
</div>
```

Now in your CSS, set them to position themselves side by side, preferably setting the span width to that of the parent_container.

In jQuery, you can now either, `hide()` and `show()` each individual `<span>` as necessary, or [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) the transition between the spans. Per your question, it sounds like you want to [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) with a slide.

Comment: Can you possibly show an example of how to animate them with jQuery?

Comment: There's an example on the documentation I posted. But providing full code for you would be inherently difficult, as you haven't provided much information about how you want to text slider to work. My suggestion is to look at the jquery doc, and tinker with the example code first.